# find parent div inside <td> with jQuery

Tags: jquery

how can I find the parent id of the div inside the table?
I have the following structure:

```
<div id="parent">
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>                                             
   <td>                                     
     <div id="child" >      
 </div>
   </td>                    
 </tr>        
</tbody>
</table>
</div> 


<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function() 
{               
   var parent = $("#child").parent().attr("id");
   alert(parent);
});
```

When the div is inside < td> parent is empty. When I move the div outside < td> it works fine. Can you help me how to find the div inside ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean you want to find the ID of the DIV that contains your table, then you can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
var parent = $("#child").parent().closest('div').attr("id");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9SRtk/1/)

**EDIT**

After reading the docs, `closest()` is better than `parents()` because it doesn't travel up to the root node. Thanks for the heads up Andy E

Comment: Use `closest('div')` rather than `parents('div:first')`.  The former is more efficient.

Answer (score 10):

You can use .closest(), it finds the closest parent which matches the specified selector. In your case:

```
 var parentId = $('#child').parent().closest('div').attr('id');
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Your current selector won't work. You need to select the parent first. The closest div to `#child` is itself.

Comment: True, I didn't know closest would also check the starting node (code corrected).

Comment: +1d! You missed out on the accept as the OP initially selected yours. Not that the +15 matters much at this point ;)

Comment: Hehehehe, well, I still have to answer quite a few more questions if I want to get anywhere close to your reputation, but I'll try ;D

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{               
   var parent = $("#child").parent().attr("id");
   alert(parent);
});
```

You are trying to read the attribute of "id" of  element and the  has no attributes of name "id".

Following code will work:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>                                             
   <td id="divParent">                                     
     <div id="child" ></div>
   </td>                    
 </tr>        
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{               
   var parent = $("#child").parents('div:first').attr("id");
   alert(parent);
});
</script>
```

This will give you alert message of "divParent".